# Collections and Variables

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, collections, stopwatch

I have a collection in Visual Basic.net (Sorry if people are seeing this code for the nine billionth time...)

Here's the code so far:

```
Public Class MainFrm

Private _storage As New List(Of StopwatchStorage)

Public TotalParticipants As Integer ' The total number of participants, will be set via an options form.
Private participantLbl As Label ' A label which will hold the ordered number.
Public participantName As TextBox ' A blank textbox to allow the user to name the participant
Private participantClock As Label ' This is a label which will display the stopwatch
Public ParticipantStop As Button ' A button used to the stop the timer on the participant.
Private participantContinue As Button ' A button used to continue the timer when accidentally stopped.
Private participantTimer As Timer ' A timer to continuously update the labels on pulses.
Public eventName As String = "" ' The Event name itself

' The options
Public numEntrants As Integer = 30 ' The maximum number of participants, set at 30 by default.
Public startingEntrants As Integer = 2 ' The number of timers to start simultaneously., set a 2 by default
Public entryTimer As Integer = 90 ' The timer to seperate and space the entries. Set to 90 by default
Public addAuto As Boolean = False ' A checkbox to determine whether or not to automatically add a participant.

Dim counterTimer As Integer ' A simple holder to count down the entryTimer.

Private participantContinueTimers As TimeSpan
Private participantContinuation As New Stopwatch ' A Stopwatch to hold the continuation timer in the event of an error
Private participantStopwatch As New Stopwatch
Private matchStopwatch As New Stopwatch

Private Sub Participant_Stop(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)
    For Each storage As StopwatchStorage In _storage
        If storage.Button Is sender Then
            storage.Stopwatch.Stop()
            storage.Button.Visible = False
            storage.ContinueBtn.Visible = True

            ' Reset the Continuation timer
            storage.Continuation.Start()
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub StartButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartButton.Click
    For indexCounter As Integer = 1 To startingEntrants Step 1
        DrawControls(indexCounter)
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub Participant_Resume(sender As Object, args As EventArgs)
    For Each storage As StopwatchStorage In _storage
        If storage.ContinueBtn Is sender Then
            storage.ContinueBtn.Visible = False
            storage.Button.Visible = True
            storage.Stopwatch.Start()
            storage.Continuation.Stop()

            ' Add the value from storage.Continuation.Elapsed to a continuing tally
            storage.ParticipantContinueTimers += storage.Continuation.Elapsed
            storage.Continuation.Reset()
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub DrawControls(records As Integer)
    participantLbl = New Label
    participantLbl.Location = New Point(5 + (((records - 1) \ 15) * 321), 5 + (((records - 1) Mod 15) * 26))
    participantLbl.Size = New Size(22, 20)
    participantLbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    participantLbl.Text = records
    CenterPanel.Controls.Add(participantLbl)

    participantName = New TextBox
    participantName.Location = New Point(31 + (((records - 1) \ 15) * 321), 5 + (((records - 1) Mod 15) * 26))
    participantName.Size = New Size(105, 20)
    CenterPanel.Controls.Add(participantName)

    participantClock = New Label
    participantClock.Size = New Size(100, 20)
    participantClock.Name = "participantClock" & TotalParticipants
    participantClock.Location = New Point(139 + (((records - 1) \ 15) * 321), 5 + (((records - 1) Mod 15) * 26))
    participantClock.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    participantClock.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    CenterPanel.Controls.Add(participantClock)

    ParticipantStop = New Button
    ParticipantStop.Size = New Size(63, 20)
    ParticipantStop.Location = New Point(245 + (((records - 1) \ 15) * 321), 5 + (((records - 1) Mod 15) * 26))
    ParticipantStop.BackColor = Color.Red
    ParticipantStop.ForeColor = Color.White
    ParticipantStop.Font = New Font(ParticipantStop.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    ParticipantStop.Text = "Stop"
    CenterPanel.Controls.Add(ParticipantStop)
    AddHandler ParticipantStop.Click, AddressOf Participant_Stop


    participantContinue = New Button
    participantContinue.Size = New Size(63, 20)
    participantContinue.Location = New Point(245 + (((records - 1) \ 15) * 321), 5 + (((records - 1) Mod 15) * 26))
    participantContinue.BackColor = Color.Green
    participantContinue.ForeColor = Color.White
    participantContinue.Font = New Font(participantContinue.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    participantContinue.Text = "Resume"
    participantContinue.Visible = False
    CenterPanel.Controls.Add(participantContinue)
    AddHandler participantContinue.Click, AddressOf Participant_Resume

    participantTimer = New Timer
    participantTimer.Start()
    participantTimer.Enabled = True
    participantTimer.Interval = 1
    participantStopwatch = New Stopwatch
    participantStopwatch.Start()


    Dim storage As New StopwatchStorage()
    storage.Label = participantClock
    storage.Timer = participantTimer
    storage.Continuation = participantContinuation
    storage.Button = ParticipantStop
    storage.ParticipantContinueTimers = participantContinueTimers
    storage.ContinueBtn = participantContinue
    storage.ParticipantName = participantName
    storage.ParticipantOrder = participantLbl
    storage.Stopwatch = participantStopwatch
    _storage.Add(storage)
    AddHandler participantTimer.Tick, AddressOf Timer_Tick

End Sub


End Class
Public Class StopwatchStorage
Public Property Stopwatch As Stopwatch
Public Property Continuation As Stopwatch
Public Property ParticipantContinueTimers As TimeSpan
Public Property ParticipantName As TextBox
Public Property Label As Label
Public Property ParticipantOrder As Label
Public Property Timer As Timer
Public Property Button As Button
Public Property ContinueBtn As Button
End Class
```

What's supposed to happen is that the Stop Button when clicked is supposed to start another timer/stopwatch. When you click the Resume Button, the value of the stopwatch is supposed to be added back onto the running timer. (It gets added to `participantContinueTimers which is then add back onto the running timer.) Now the code is doing what it's supposed to do, BUT, instead of adding the particular of that one stopped clock, it adds ALL of the values of the stopped click then resets.

Can someone explain how can I get this to work so that only the ONE stopped result is added on?

EDIT: Adding in the method in which the Storages are made. Any more code and I'll have to host it on SourceForge or Codeplex and work from there.

Comment: I've not understood the question itself. Can you explain following bit more: "instead of adding the particular of that one stopped clock, it adds ALL of the values of the stopped click then resets."

Comment: The program is dynamically creating controls. Two stopwatches are made. One runs on creation (TimerA for instance) and one runs when the one created stops (Timer B). What's supposed to happen is that by the advent of clicking on a Continue button, the value of Timer B is supposed to be added back onto Timer A and then Timer A supposed to run again. This is supposed to happen for just that ONE particular timer. If I make 30 timers, stop 29 of them and then try to resume any one of those 29, instead of just adding the value of the one TimerB, it adds up ALL of the TimerB's instead.

Comment: You haven't shown how you are creating those StopwatchStorages. So maybe you are using same references for something that is causing this behaviour.

Comment: Edited in how (I think) the storages are made. Not sure if I can post up anymore code without posting up the entire form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use member variables for your dynamical controls. On this way you are overriding all controls and only the last one wins. Instead you should create them in the method separately. You are also using a parameter `records`, but i don't see the code where you loop it to create more than one `StopwatchStorage`.

```
Private Sub DrawControls(records As Integer)
    Dim participantLbl = New Label
    participantLbl.Location = New Point(5 + (((records - 1) \ 15) * 321), 5 + (((records - 1) Mod 15) * 26))
    participantLbl.Size = New Size(22, 20)
    participantLbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    participantLbl.Text = records
    CenterPanel.Controls.Add(participantLbl)

    Dim participantName = New TextBox
    participantName.Location = New Point(31 + (((records - 1) \ 15) * 321), 5 + (((records - 1) Mod 15) * 26))
    participantName.Size = New Size(105, 20)
    CenterPanel.Controls.Add(participantName)

    Dim participantClock = New Label
    participantClock.Size = New Size(100, 20)
    participantClock.Name = "participantClock" & TotalParticipants
    participantClock.Location = New Point(139 + (((records - 1) \ 15) * 321), 5 + (((records - 1) Mod 15) * 26))
    participantClock.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    participantClock.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    CenterPanel.Controls.Add(participantClock)

    Dim ParticipantStop = New Button
    ParticipantStop.Size = New Size(63, 20)
    ParticipantStop.Location = New Point(245 + (((records - 1) \ 15) * 321), 5 + (((records - 1) Mod 15) * 26))
    ParticipantStop.BackColor = Color.Red
    ParticipantStop.ForeColor = Color.White
    ParticipantStop.Font = New Font(ParticipantStop.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    ParticipantStop.Text = "Stop"
    CenterPanel.Controls.Add(ParticipantStop)
    AddHandler ParticipantStop.Click, AddressOf Participant_Stop


    Dim participantContinue = New Button
    participantContinue.Size = New Size(63, 20)
    participantContinue.Location = New Point(245 + (((records - 1) \ 15) * 321), 5 + (((records - 1) Mod 15) * 26))
    participantContinue.BackColor = Color.Green
    participantContinue.ForeColor = Color.White
    participantContinue.Font = New Font(participantContinue.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
    participantContinue.Text = "Resume"
    participantContinue.Visible = False
    CenterPanel.Controls.Add(participantContinue)
    AddHandler participantContinue.Click, AddressOf Participant_Resume

    Dim participantTimer = New Timer
    participantTimer.Start()
    participantTimer.Enabled = True
    participantTimer.Interval = 1
    participantStopwatch = New Stopwatch
    participantStopwatch.Start()


    Dim storage As New StopwatchStorage()
    storage.Label = participantClock
    storage.Timer = participantTimer
    storage.Continuation = participantContinuation
    storage.Button = ParticipantStop
    storage.ParticipantContinueTimers = participantContinueTimers
    storage.ContinueBtn = participantContinue
    storage.ParticipantName = participantName
    storage.ParticipantOrder = participantLbl
    storage.Stopwatch = participantStopwatch
    _storage.Add(storage)
    AddHandler participantTimer.Tick, AddressOf Timer_Tick
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited my response to show how I'm looping through to create the storages. Speicifcally the function: StartButton_Click

Comment: @Paul: So does my answer solve your problem? As i've said, you are creating `n` StopWatchStorages but all referencing the same controls.

Comment: Doesn't unfortunately. I still have the same problem. Unless your code doesn't change anything, it looks like mine still.

Comment: No, i'm creating the controls in the method locally, for example: `Dim participantLbl = New Label`. You are initializing instance variables declared class-wide, for example: `participantLbl = New Label`. Your code will only use one reference(for each control), mine will create `n` controls with different references.

Comment: Okay I see it now. But no I'm still having the same result. Should I get rid of the declarations at the start of the form then?

Comment: @Paul: Yes, of course(see the first sentence of my answer). My code would not even compile otherwise because i'm using the same variable names as your instance variables.

Comment: After editing the code and getting rid of the extraneous declared statements, this now works. Thank you Tim. It still let me compile the code for some reason.